# Implementing Linkedin Share API

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to use linkedin API for sharing my web site post on linkedIn.

While making an rest api call to linkedin, I am gettting below error:

{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Invalid arguments: {S_400_BAD_REQUEST=Bad request}",
  "status": 400,
}

I am getting invalid arguments error. However, I am passing all the required arguments as described in LinkedIn documentation.

Please help if anyone faced and resolved above error.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the rest api and used the js api, it was much easier. I coded almost exactly what you are trying to code, so it could help you greatly. You can find it here: https://github.com/kaburkett/LinkedIn-Advanced-Share

Answer (score 0):

To share on LinkedIn, all you need is:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Works fine:

[image]

Just make your own button, stylize it, and hyperlink it.  No need for a plugin or SDK or jslib bundle or whatever.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]