# share a post on linkedIn with react-native

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

I have an app built in react native in which I need to share a post on linkedIn with predefined content(can be image or text).

I used 'react-native-share' for sharing content on facebook, instagram and twitter but It does not provide the support for LinkedIn. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018637/react-native-how-to-share-a-message-to-a-particular-person-on-linkedin

Comment: Hey, does this help?  [StackOverflow: Implementing Linkedin Share API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855029/2430549)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module

```
react-native-linkedin
```

[Refer Here](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin)

Hope it works !